# VmWare-Clarity Right aligned panel/bar

Tags: vmware-clarity

What's the best way to have a layout with two nav-bars?
A left-aligned sidebar and a right-aligned bar ?
Sidenav is always placed on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Clarity does not currently have a right panel, an application would have to do this themselves with a custom implementation.